# How to enable camera's take photo option in iOS10

Tags: ios, camera, uiimagepickercontroller

In iOS10 click camera an option of take photo not manual click that one automatically taken photo so how can create take photo with manual click?
I tried this following code:

```
- (void)cameraAndPhotogalleryMethod{
UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];

if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera])
{
    picker.delegate = self;
    picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
    picker.cameraDevice = UIImagePickerControllerCameraDeviceFront;
    picker.showsCameraControls = YES;
    [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES
                     completion:^ {
                         [picker takePicture];
                     }];
}
else
{
    picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
}}

- (void)cameraMethod{
UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc]init];
picker.delegate = self;
picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
picker.cameraDevice = UIImagePickerControllerCameraDeviceFront;
picker.showsCameraControls = YES;
[self presentViewController:picker animated:YES
                 completion:^ {
                     [picker takePicture];
                 }];}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this properties in info.plist file

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1.If you Access the camera on ios 10.You should add the code in plist.Try this code.

```
<key>NSCameraUsageDescription</key>
<string>$(PRODUCT_NAME) needs access to use your camera</string>
<key>NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription</key>
<string>$(PRODUCT_NAME) needs access to use your photo  library</string>
```